# php variable overflowing in ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

This is a theoretical question.  I know exactly what's going wrong, I just don't see a way around it.

I'm calling calling *php page B* from *php page A* in an ajax request and submitting a query in *php page B*.  I'm trying to get the data back to *php page A* as a json_encoded array.  The problem is that the json variable is overflowing (maxing out the memory_limit).

As a result I'm getting an exception:

```
[object Object] parsererror SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
```

If I wasn't trying to get this data back as a json_encoded array for purposes of displaying it, I would just echo the data to the screen rather than store it in the variable.  But, since I need to get that data back as a json_encoded array, I kind of have to store it.

The only solution I can think of is to simply echo the data out on *php page B* and change the way I'm handling the date on *page A* (i.e. not expecting json as the dataType).

Is there any other possible way (barring limiting the rows returned from the query)?

**EDIT**: I also don't want to change any of the settings in the php.ini.  There has to be a clever solution without mucking around with settings.

Comment: Request n rows at a time, until there are no more rows, populating an array. When done, encode the array. though, you may still run into the same issue. If you do, then request n at a time and return n at a time back to the browser, and request more until no more are available. (aka pagination)

Comment: How big is the array? If you really need it, you can modify php's memory limit. You might just move the problem though, if the server can't handle it, what about the browser?

Comment: @KevinB, can you elaborate, as an answer, perhaps?

Comment: well, i can't really give any code, all i can really do is expand on the thought process.

Comment: @KevinB.  Ok, I'll research pagination.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pagination to request the data from the server. Essentially, you'll request n results at a time, until you reach a page number that returns 0 results. So, instead of requesting 20k records at once, you'll request 1000 records 20 times in succession (or whatever number you page your data at).

```
var resultArr = [];
var url = "foo.php";

function handleData(data) {
    // do stuff with data here
    console.log(data);
}

function getData(url,page) {
    $.ajax(url,{data: { page: page}, type: "GET", dataType:"json"}).done(function(data){
        if (data.length != 0) {
            resultArr = resultArr.concat(data);
            getData(url,page+1);
        }
        else {
            handleData(resultArr);
        }
    });
}   

getData(url,0);
```

And for your query, limit it to `n` rows starting with `$_GET["page"]*n+1`

Comment: could this also be performed with $_POST ?

Comment: yes, it would be no different other than replacing GET with POST.